# Can I use linq to remove items from asp .net DropDownList.Items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dropdownbox

As title says, is it possible to use LINQ to remove Items from a DropDownList's .Items where the Item is not equal to strings that I specify?

To put it another way - I have a list of strings, if an Item doesn't match any string in the list, it is removed.

NOTE: I know how to achieve this, I can do it with a foreach loop. That's fine - but I want to know if there's a LINQ alternative.

EDIT: I should say - the Item's **.Text** property matches any item in the list of strings.

EDIT: For those interested, this was my proposed 'foreach' way:

```
        private void FilterDropDownChoices(List<String> permittedChoices)
        {
            foreach(ListItem item in ddlChoices.Items)
            {
                if (!permittedChoices.Contains(item.Text))
                {
                    ddlChoices.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tested that?  You should actually be getting an error with that code, because you cannot change a collection while you are iterating through it.

Comment: I haven't tested it no, it was half-heartedly thrown together really quickly as I'm waiting for this linq alternative. Given that error you've just mentioned - I'll get and set the collection of items outside of the foreach (use another local collection) if there's no suggested LINQ alternative. Thanks @ryanulit.

Comment: What you have here is a `foreach` loop that is used to cause side effects (mutate the `Items` collection).  Linq is not a replacement for that.  Linq is for *querying* which is not what you are doing.  [Further reading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).  The best you could do is get the set of items to remove via LINQ. You'll still want to have a `foreach` loop to actuall remove them though.

Comment: Curiosity: why were you intent on needing LINQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ryanulit actually provided the best answer.

The problem is that the ListItemCollection implements only the IEnumerable interface. LINQ extensions works upon IEnumerable<T>. Hence, casting (IEnumerable) to (IEnumerable<T>) - you can now use LINQ.

So, to answer your question:

```
ddlChoices.Items
.Cast<ListItem>()
.Where(item => !permittedChoices.Contains(item.Text))
.ToList()
.ForEach(ddlChoices.Items.Remove);
```

You have to use ToList() or ToArray() or similar because you can't modify a collection while reading from it - ToList() copies the references to the selected items which then can be looped over and removed from the ListItemCollection.

While writing this I saw Matten's comment - He highlighted useful functionality of the ListItemCollection (being able to remove items by their text property) but got the question wrong. The requirement was: you are only allow to have 'permittedChoices' inside ddlChoices.Items. Matten's example removes the valid choices and leaving the invalid ones which is the opposite of what he asked.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is a query language, it is not used to modify your data.
what you can do, it query your list of items for the condition you like and than effect the collection by your self.

sample:

```
var relevant = from item in list.Items
               where permittedChoices.Contains(item.ToString())
               select item
```

and than you can clear the Items list and add only the relevant you want.

```
ddlChoices.Clear();
ddlChoices.AddRange(relevant.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to use linq? Here you go :-)

```
private static void FilterDropDownChoices(List<String> permittedChoices)
{
    ddlChoices.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
       .Where(li => permittedChoices.Contains(li.Text))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(ddlChoices.Items.Remove);
}
```